# YouTube GData API

Tags: api, zend-framework, youtube, gdata, subscriptions

I'm using the Zend Framework (php) and I'm trying to retrieve a list of the most recent videos uploaded by all of the users I subscribe to.  Similar to what you would see if you visit your Subscriptions page on youtube.com.

I can make a request using getSubscriptionFeed() for all the users I subscribe to.  Then I can iterate through each one and make a request for getUserUploads() then pop off the first item, but it takes forever and seems like a lot of unnecessary work.  There must be a single query I can make with all of the user names I want to find.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested:

The most recent version of the Zend Framework (1.11.10) does not include the all-important method to retrieve the newest videos from your subscriptions as documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions.html#Retrieving_new_subscription_videos) on google's site.

So I simply added:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a feed of a user's subscriptions
 *
 * @param string $user (optional) The username of interest
 * @param mixed $location (optional) The URL to query or a
 *         Zend_Gdata_Query object from which a URL can be determined
 * @return Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoFeed The newest video for each subscription
 */
public function getNewSubscriptionVideos($user = null, $location = null)
{
    if ($user !== null) {
        $uri = self::USER_URI . '/' . $user . '/newsubscriptionvideos';
    } else if ($location instanceof Zend_Gdata_Query) {
        $uri = $location->getQueryUrl();
    } else {
        $uri = $location;
    }
    return parent::getFeed($uri, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoFeed');
}
```

to the YouTube.php document in the Zend/GData directory on line 561 (after the **getSubscriptionFeed** method).

Now I can call **getNewSubscriptionVideos** method and pass it a username or 'default' and it will return an array of VideoEntities that can be accessed using:

```
$raw_new_subscription_videos = $_youtube->getNewSubscriptionVideos($username);

foreach ($raw_new_subscription_videos as $video)
{
  $title = $video->getVideoTitle();

  // etc.
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else who is as lost as I was for the past few hours.

Howie

Comment: It is usually inadvisable to directly modify lib files - "hacking the core" - like those in the ZF lib; makes upgrading a problem as the new version won't have your modifications. Better is to create your own class - something like `My_Gdata_YouTube extends Zend_Gdata_YouTube` - and add your new method there. And then, as a cherry on top, maybe submit an [issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/) for the omitted functionality and then contribute a patch back to the ZF project itself. ;-)

Comment: thats a great idea - didn't even cross my mind - i was so excited that the code I added worked.  I'll do that.